# PHP 7.2 64bit nts "php.exe - Entry Point Not Found" errors for "C:/php -v"

Tags: php-7.2

I just installed PHP 7.2.7 (x64) & Windows Cache Extension 2.0 (x64) for PHP 7.2 using the Web Platform Installer.

However when I run any php command such as `php -v` the following popups appear!

Message Box 1: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **vspprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 2: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **strpprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 3: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **spprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 4: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **vspprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 5: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **zend_wrong_paramers_count_error@@24** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 6: [php.exe - Ordinal Not Found] The ordinal 407 could not be located in the dynamic link library SSLEAY32.dll.

Message Box 7 & 8: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **spprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 9: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **call_user_function_ex** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 10: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **spprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 11: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **strpprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Message Box 12: [php.exe - Entry Point Not Found] The procedure entry point **spprintf** could not be located in the dynamic link library php7.dll.

Finally it outputs the following at the Command Prompt:

PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 19 2018 23:13:48) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

I've tried disabling Extensions etc. but I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existance of an "old" PHPRC environment variable will cause the wrong php.ini file to be loaded.

The `PHPRC` System variable needed to be updated to the correct path.

Steps:

1. Go to: `Control Panel > System and Security > System > System Properties > Environment Variables > System variables`
2. Edit the `PHPRC` path to point to the correct path. E.g., `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\`
3. Open a new Command Prompt window then verify that `C:/php -v` works.